# Define Datalist HeaderTemplate in c# from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote following code in aspx, and the problem is that i need to create same datalist from code behind in C#:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color: Black;">
                <div style="color: White; font-size: medium; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                    TEST</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    date</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    Buy/Sell</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    Call/Put</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    name</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    amount</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    price1</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: #E3E2E7; padding: 5px; font-size: x-small;">
                    price2</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #71B24C; color: White; height: 50px; text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("option")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #ADAAB1; color: White; height: 50px; padding-right: 5px;
                        font-size: medium; text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("date")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #D9D9D3; padding-right: 5px; height: 50px; font-size: medium;
                        text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("type")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #D9D9D3; padding-right: 5px; height: 50px; font-size: medium;
                        text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("action")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #D9D9D3; padding-right: 5px; height: 50px; font-size: medium;
                        text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("pos_name")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #D9D9D3; padding-right: 5px; height: 50px; font-size: medium;
                        text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("amount")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #D9D9D3; padding-right: 5px; height: 50px; font-size: medium;
                        text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("unitPrice")%></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background-color: #D9D9D3; padding-right: 5px; height: 50px; font-size: medium;
                        text-align: center;">
                        <%# Eval("total")%></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I mean that code that i demonstrating works perfectly in aspx page. I am interesting in getting same effect (display datalist) but through the code behind. I mean to code in code behind something like : DataList = new DataList(); My problem is, i dont know how to work with HeaderTemplate within code behind.
If you can provide example code, it would be nice!

Comment: Hi! It's unclear 100% what do you want... Put more info.

Comment: I'm also in the dark..somebody voted up...strange...

Comment: I mean that code that i demonstrating works perfectly in aspx page. I am interesting in getting same effect (display datalist) but through the code behind. I mean to code in code behind something like : DataList = new DataList(); My problem is, i dont know how to work with HeaderTemplate within code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HeaderTemplate in code behind must be of type ITemplate.  Please refer to these articles for information on creating a template.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate(v=VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WEB.UI.WEBCONTROLS.DATALIST.HEADERTEMPLATE);k(HEADERTEMPLATE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Hope they can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with DataLists, but from looking over [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfx4t9t7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) it looks like what you'll want to do is bind your data source to the DataList in your code-behind and then use asp controls on the aspx page to display the bound data.

So, you'll want to bind your data to the list:

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(cString)) {
    conn.Open();
    comm = new SqlCommand(selString, conn);
    DataList1.DataSource = comm.ExecuteReader();
    DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

and then format your DataList to load data from the bound source like you've already done, with statements like `<%# Eval("date")%>`.

MSDN also has a page on [how to create ASP.NET Server controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yc8bb09%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

> 1. In the .aspx file, insert an element inside the control to identify what template you are creating, as in the following example:
>
> ```
> <asp:DataList id="DataList1" runat="server">
>   <ItemTemplate>
>
>   </ItemTemplate>
> </asp:DataList>
> ```
>
> 2. Inside the template element, add HTML text and other controls as the template's content. Include property and data-binding values for the embedded controls using normal syntax, as in the following example:
>
> ```
> <asp:DataList id="DataList3" runat="server">
>   <ItemTemplate>
>    Name: <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
>    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.EmployeeName")%>'/>
>   </ItemTemplate>
> </asp:DataList>
> ```
>
> 3. Repeat Steps 1 and 2 for each template you want to create.